# jQuery button onclick event not recognised on dynamic modal content form

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am generating dynamic content for my `modal-body` which includes a comment submit form. I put together a function that on click of the submit button is supposed to trigger an AJAX call to handle the comment submission, but for whatever reason nothing is happening once I click the button.

I tried various ways of trapping the trigger event like `$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {` or `$('.class').click(function(){` but none trigger anything.

The only time I get a result is when I change the submit button type from `type="button"` to `type="submit"`, however, this results in an unwanted full page reload which is not desired as the modal is supposed to remain open.

Appreciate any advice, obviously the console is empty and any `alert();` are not triggered as well.

**Modal Body Content - Comment Form - populated via previous AJAX call**

```
<!-- Begin post comment form -->
<form id=\"modal-comment-form\" name=\"modal-comment-form\" class=\"form margin-top-50\" action=\"\" method=\"\">
    <h4>leave a comment:</h4>
    <div class=\"row\">
        <div class=\"col-lg-12\">
            <div class=\"form-group\">
                <textarea class=\"form-control\" id=\"modal-comment-message\" name=\"modal-comment-message\" rows=\"3\" placeholder=\"your comment*\" required></textarea>
                <input id=\"modal-comment-task-id\" name=\"modal-comment-task-id\" type=\"hidden\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"\" value=\"".$task_id."\" readonly required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=\"row\">
        <div class=\"col-lg-12\">
            <button type=\"button\" id=\"modal_comment_submit\" name=\"modal_comment_submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary modal-comment\">submit comment</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- End post comment form -->
```

jQuery to check modal comment button submit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // modal comment submit
    $('#modal_comment_submit').click(function(e) {
        console.log('Comment submit button clicked.');

        // check if textarea has content or not
        if ($('#modal-comment-message').val() != '') {
            console.log('Modal comment textarea is not empty');

            $('#modal_comment_submit').prop('disabled', true); // disable submit button
            var task_id = e.find('input[name="modal-comment-task-id"]').val(); // obtain task id from hidden field

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'path/to/script.php',
                data: 'action=add_new_comment&app_id=4&article_id=' + task_id + '&user_id=1&' + $('#modal-comment-form').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    // show success message
                    $('#comment_output').html(response);
                    // remove success message after 5 sec
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#comment_output').empty().hide();
                    }, 5000);

                    // enable submit button
                    $('#modal_comment_submit').prop('disabled', false);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log('Ajax POST request failed.');
                    console.error(xhr);
                    alert('Error: ' + xhr);
                }
            });

        } else {
            console.log('Form on submit is invalid');
            alert("Please enter a comment");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Need to delegate events using `.on()` when content is dynamically created.

Comment: I tried `$('#modal_comment_submit').on('click', function(e) {` but no response either?

Comment: Try `$("#modal-comment-form").on("click", "#modal_comment_submit", function(e){})`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it works, but alas the below trigger did the trick.

```
$(document).on('click', '#modal_comment_submit', function(e) {
    console.log('Modal comment submit button clicked.');
});
```